# MongoDB - Finding the parent object based on a very nested property

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection that consists of posts. Inside those post objects are properties about the post, one of which being an array of tags associated with the post. Inside the array of tags are more objects, each of which are the tags with a name property. I would like to get back all the posts from this collection which have a given tag in them based on the name of the tag.

Here is an example of a post object within the collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c6a0478cba09c148b497fc6"),
    "tags" : [
        {
            "_id" : "5c69d974e05511106048780e",
            "name" : "Food",
            "text_color" : "#ffffff",
            "bg_color" : "#02569b",
            "createdAt" : "2019-02-17T22:00:20.143Z",
            "updatedAt" : "2019-02-17T22:00:20.143Z",
            "__v" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : "5c69d95de05511106048780d",
            "name" : "Drinks",
            "text_color" : "#ffffff",
            "bg_color" : "#0175c2",
            "createdAt" : "2019-02-17T21:59:57.758Z",
            "updatedAt" : "2019-02-17T21:59:57.758Z",
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ],
    "title" : "Title of the post",
    "body" : "body of the post",
    "author_id" : ObjectId("5c5e0d3b647f12e949cbea1e"),
    "author_name" : "garrett",
    "likes_count" : 1,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-02-18T01:03:52.497Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-02-28T00:25:21.969Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "dislikes_count" : 0
}
```

Of course I have other post objects in this collection, some of which may have different tags. How can I get all posts with the food tag to be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) query will do the job here. Here's how it looks

```
const tagName = 'food;
db.posts.find({ 'tags.name': tagName }).then(console.log);
```

Comment: This works, I really thought this would be more complicated. Didn't realize you could use dot notation like that within the query.